# PasswordResetConfirmView..as_view() in Django redirect to Django administration site

Tags: python, django

I am using **Django 3** to develop a website where password reset has done through e-mail conformation.
After clicking the link in the email, it takes to the Django Administration Password reset confirmation page, rather taking me to the my developed web page. I am following Django 3 by example book. These codes is from chapter 4 of this book.

***Please help. Thanks in advance.***

[Here is the project GitHub link.](https://github.com/faysal077/Bookmark)

Here is the urls.py of the app (named as "account")

```
urlpatterns = [
#path('login/', views.user_Login, name='login'),
# Log-in and Logout
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
path('',dashboard,name='dashboard'),
# change password urls
path('password_change/',auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(),name='password_change'),
path('password_change/done/',auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(),name='password_change_done'),
# reset password urls
path('password_reset/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),name='password_reset'),
path('password_reset/done/',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset/done/',auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_engine='accounts/password_change_form.html'),name='password_reset_complete'),
```

]

***settings.py***

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'account.apps.AccountConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',]


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
```

***templates/registration/login.html***

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}
{% block content%}
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>
            Your username and passwoed didn't match.
            Please try again.
        </p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Please, use the following form to log-in:</p>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="login-form">
        <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p><a href="{% url "password_reset" %}">Forgotten your password?</a> </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
            <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

***templates/registration/logged_out.html***

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Logged out{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Logged out</h1>
    <p>
    You have successfully logged out.
    You can <a href="{% url "login" %}">log-in-again</a>
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

***templates/registration/password_change_done.html***

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Logged out{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Logged out</h1>
    <p>
    You have successfully logged out.
    You can <a href="{% url "login" %}">log-in-again</a>
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

***templates/registration/password_change_form.html***

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Change your password{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Change your password</h1>
    <p>Use the form below to change your password.</p>
    <form method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Change"></p>
    {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

***templates/registration/password_reset_ confirm.html***

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Reset your password{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Reset your password.</h1>
    {% if validlink %}
        <p>Please enter your new password twice:</p>
        <form method="post" action="password_change_form.html">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Change my password"></p>
        </form>
    {% else %}
        <p>The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used. Please request a new password reset.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

***templates/registration/password_reset_complete.html***

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Password reset{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Password set</h1>
    <p>Your password has been set. You can <a href="{% url "login" %}">log in now</a> </p>
{% endblock %}
```

***templates/registration/password_reset_done.html***

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Reset your password{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Reset your password</h1>
    <p>We've emailed you instruction for setting your password.</p>
    <p>If you don't receieve an email, please make sure you've enter the address you reginstered with.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

***templates/registration/password_reset_email.html***

```html
Someone asked for password resent for email {{ email }}. Follow the link below:
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url "password_reset_confirm" uidb64=uid token=token %}
Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.get_username }}
```

***templates/registration/password_reset_form.html***

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Reset your password{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Forgotten your password ?</h1>
    <p>Enter your e-mail address to obtain a new password.</p>
    <form method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Sent e-mail"></p>
    {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Email Screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vESC.png)

This link open to this page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXcEZ.png)

Comment: plz provide minimal, reproducible Example . [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi bhucho, Thanks for your respond. My problem is what link (for new password set ) in E-mail. That do not take me to the **templates/registration/password_change_form.html**. Rather it takes me to the Django administration Password reset confirmation page. I have attached screenshots. here.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem I can think of is that Django doesn't know where to search for reset password HTML files, that's why is it showing the default ones.
To override the default, you need to pass `template_name` to the`as_view` so that it knows what to render. One example is given below.

```
path('reset_password/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html.html'),
     name='reset_password'),
```

Comment: Hi @abdullah_adeel, thanks for your reply. 
I have tried this, but my developed customized website is not shown. it redirect to the Django Administration Password reset page.
Thanks

Comment: Ok you can try another thing, try changing the name of the folder from `templates/registration/<you_file_name>` to `templates/EmailRegs/<your_file_names>`. Change it in the urls.py as well as the actual folder name.